# mongo --shell file.js and "use" statement

Tags: mongodb, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

can't find solution for simple question:

I have file **text.js**

```
use somedb
db.somecollection.findOne()
```

When I run this file in cmd with redirection command from file:
**"mongo < text.js"**

it's **work properly**

But when I try this way

"mongo text.js" or "mongo --shell test.js"

I got this error message

MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
type "help" for help
Wed Dec 05 16:05:21 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement *pathToFile*\test.js.js:1
failed to load:  *pathToFile*\test.js.js

It's fail on "use somedb". If I remove this line, it's run without error, but console is clear.

is there any idea, what is this and how to fix?

I'm tying to find sollution for this, to create build tool for Sublime Text 2. 
default build file was

```
{
"cmd": ["mongo","$file"]
}
```

but in this case I get the error above

PS. right after posting this question I find sollution for **SublimeText2**:

```
{
"selector": "source.js",
"shell":true,
"cmd": ["mongo < ${file}"]
}
```

PSS. right after posting this question I find sollution for **SublimeText3**:

```
{
"selector": "source.js",
"shell":true,
"cmd": ["mongo","<", "$file"]
}
```

this build tool work properly

Comment: I'm tying to find sollution for this for create build tool for Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 9):

`use dbname` is a helper function in the interactive shell which does not work when you are using mongo shell with a JS script file like you are.

There are multiple solutions to this.   The best one, IMO is to explicitly pass the DB name along with host and port name to mongo like this:

`mongo hostname:27017/dbname` mongoscript.js    //  replace 27017 with your port number

A better way to do this would be to define the DB at the beginning of your script:

```
mydb=db.getSiblingDB("yourdbname");
mydb.collection.findOne();
etc.
```

The latter is preferable as it allows you to interact with multiple DBs in the same script if you need to do so.

Comment: Yes, just a note, for a full mapping between mongo shell helper commands and their JS equivalents, that can be used in your js script file, see mongo documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the database while starting the mongo client:

```
mongo somedb text.js
```

To get the output from the client to stdout just use the printjson function in your script:

```
printjson(db.somecollection.findOne());
```

Comment: the Idea was specify db in js file. I saw this initialization of mongo shell before. As for "printjson" thx, but there is also exist some issue. When we run "printjson(db.somecollection.findOne());" we get result. When we try run "printjson(db.somecollection.find());", seems it print whole cursor object, but not a result. Without printjson it's nothing return.

Comment: You can just iterate the result in a while loop in your script and call printjson for each individual object: while (cursor.hasNext()) printjson(cursor.next());

Answer (score 0):

Mongo needs to be invoked from a shell to get that mode, with Ansible you would have this:

```
- name: mongo using different databases
  action: shell /usr/bin/mongo < text.js
```

Instead of this:

```
- name: mongo breaking
  command: /usr/bin/mongo < text.js
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me on Windows + Sublime Text 2 + MongoDB 2.6.5

```
{
    "selector": "source.js",
    "shell":true,
    "cmd": ["mongo","<", "$file"],
    "working_dir" : "C:\\MongoDB\\bin"
}
```